# Youtrack Workflow - Summary of Issues on Shedule Rule

Tags: workflow, rule, youtrack

I'm struggling with the web based javascript workflow editor in youtrack. what i trying to achieve is to create a summarized list of tasks from current project with the worklog times sums and send that to the project leader. 
Unfortunately i cannot achieve that. I'm not very familiar with the syntax and the documentation is pretty weird, maybe somebody of you folks can help me out.

Ok, lets explain what i did:

1. i created a sheduled workflow and attached to the project
2. starting coding

now im facing different problems. First i dont even receive a message. Normally the workflow should be fired every minute (for testing) because of the cron:

```
  cron: '* * * * * *',
```

the next thing is the search rule what i dont really know if its right:

```
 search: 'work time: {This month}',
```

here i want to get all issues with work time tracked this month

then the next question is how to get access to the tasks, loop thru them and make some operations to summ the worktime.

At least the complete code

[image]

What i want to achieve, sending the mail with following content:

- JT-42622 with 3,5 hours worktime tracked
- JT-XXXXX with 2h
- JT-XXXXX with 3h

SUMM: 8,5H worktime out of xxx estimated

Comment: You need to set the search query to one issue because currently it will send a notification for each issue found by the search. If you need only one notification, you need to set there something like search: #A_RANDOM_ISSUE_ID with only one ID.
Then, in the body of your rule itself, use the Search module: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/incloud/2017.2/v1-Search.html to make searches and iterate over the results.
After that store the found data somewhere, form a notification with the results and send it.

Comment: As for the cron, I suggest using something like `0 0 0/1 1/1 * ? *` to trigger the rule hourly, this shouldn't impact the performance of your instance as badly as it would with minutes.